# edit django form with instance always loads with empty form fields

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

## models.py

```
class summary_model(models.Model):
    username = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    summary=models.TextField(unique=False, blank=False, null=False)
    numberofprojects=models.CharField(max_length=264, unique=False, blank=False, null=False)
    numberofinternships=models.CharField(max_length=264, unique=False, blank=False, null=False)
    numberofjobs=models.CharField(max_length=264, unique=False, blank=False, null=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.username)
```

## forms.py

```
class summary_form(forms.ModelForm):
    #fields from model
    class Meta:
        model = summary_model
        fields = ('summary','numberofprojects','numberofinternships','numberofjobs')
```

## views.py

```
def summaryview(request):
    username=request.user
    if request.method == 'GET':
        summaryform=summary_form(request.GET or None,instance=summary_model.objects.get(username=username))
        print(summaryform)
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        form4=summary_form(request.POST or None,instance=summary_model.objects.get(username=username))
        if form4.is_valid():
            summary_obj = form4.save(commit=False)
            summary_obj.username = request.user
            summary_obj.save()
            return redirect('#anotherview')
        else:
            summaryform=summary_form(instance =summary_model.objects.get(username =username))
    return render(request,'app/summary.html',{'summaryform':summary_form,})
```

## template/summary.html

```
{% block content %}
<form action="" method="post" novalidate>
{% csrf_token %}
{{ summaryform.non_field_errors }}
<div class="row form-row bg-white has-shadow">
  <div class="col-12">
    <span class="labelspan">{{ summaryform.summary.label }}</span>
    {{ summaryform.summary.errors }}
    <span class="inputfieldspan">{{ summaryform.summary}}</span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6">
    <span class="labelspan">{{ summaryform.numberofprojects.label }}</span>
    {{ summaryform.numberofprojects.errors }}
    <span class="inputfieldspan">{{ summaryform.numberofprojects}}</span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6">
    <span class="labelspan">{{ summaryform.numberofinternships.label }}</span>
    {{ summaryform.numberofinternships.errors }}
    <span class="inputfieldspan">{{ summaryform.numberofinternships}}</span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6">
    <span class="labelspan">{{ summaryform.numberofjobs.label }}</span>
    {{ summaryform.numberofjobs.errors }}
    <span class="inputfieldspan">{{ summaryform.numberofjobs}}</span>
  </div>
</div>
{{ summaryform.message.help_text }}
<button type="submit" class="btn3">Save and Continue</button></form>
{% endblock %}
```

i need to take input in summary form and allow user to edit using the same view.when i save the filled data its updating but the main issue is its not populating data in the form from the database using instance.

Comment: Most likely, there is some sort of exception when you instantiate the form, but you hide that with your blank `except`. Never, ever, ever do that.

Comment: @DanielRoseman removed try and except block still no error and still form loads with empty fields[edited my views]

Comment: @DanielRoseman Thank you for your support ...its my stupid mistake just the mistake in name {instead of passing the instantiated form i passed the initial form to templatee}

Answer (score 0):

Try 
    fields = ['summary','numberofprojects','numberofinternships','numberofjobs']
into forms.py

Comment: Thank you for your support ...its my stupid mistake just the mistake in name {instead of passing the instantiated form i passed the initial form to templatee}